# I cant add an activity after cloning from git (android studio)

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Like the title says. I'm not able to create a new activity after cloning from Git

Comment: Try to create the activity by right-clicking on the app folder instead of in the File on the navbar.

Comment: nope, still cant. if it helps, im on bumblebee

Comment: does this happen with any other project?

Comment: yes. it does :(

Comment: Try to clone it on another project and see what happens